# Is it semantically valid to put a <button> inside a <h2>?

Tags: html

I have a header element which needs to fire off some JavaScript when clicked. I know I should only use `<a>` tags when the page is actually changing, and that `<button>`s are preferred for JS functions, but for some reason it just feels wrong to do

```
<h2><button onclick="myFunction();">My Title</button></h2>
```

I can't put my finger on why that doesn't feel semantically correct. Is it just me?

Comment: See [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: What is the actual text for your button? Would it be appropriate as a heading on it's own?

Comment: Yeah, the text for the button is the title of the content that's being revealed onclick.

Comment: button isn't preferred for js functions, its for ajax on the page. regardless of how it feels to you, its the proper use....the part about your feelings really makes me think this isn't even a real question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is the actual text for your button? Would it be appropriate as a heading on it's own?

> the text for the button is the title of the content that's being revealed onclick

Then I think you're in good shape. I will however make a small suggestion that might make you feel better:

```
<h2><a href="#content">My Heading</a></h2>
<element id="content"> [your content] </element>
```

Then attach an `onclick` handler in an external javascript file. If you remove it later the link will still be valid.

Answer (score 24):

According to [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org), there's no problem in doing that.

You can try validating this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>I AM YOUR DOCUMENT TITLE REPLACE ME</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2><button onclick="myFunction();">My Title</button></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I suggest avoiding inline styles.

Comment: He's not asking if it's *technically* valid, he's asking about semantics.

Comment: I think @sanjay wants to know if it's considered meaningful in some way, not if it's valid code.  Good to know it's valid code, but not really an answer to his question.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Then the question is primarily opinion-based, because there's no objective way to test semantic validity.

Comment: The only relevance here *is* validity. Otherwise it is the same as "Why put a BUTTON in a DIV?"

Comment: @user2864740 Marking up a list with `<div>` instead of `<li>` is valid as well, however it is not semantically correct.

Comment: @WesleyMurch The semantics in that case come from using different elements, not a different valid nesting of elements. (And then the OP goes on to BUTTON vs A while ignoring the heading, so ..)

Comment: It is important to know if it is technically correct and then decide if it is semantically correct. For example it would be correct in a drop-down item. Since the header is essential, but the button is also essential. To improve accessibility, the user must know what type of element it is, and thus avoid having to apply a role = button to the heading. I was wondering if it was correct in terms of html validation. So thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

**HTML5 standard quote that says you can**

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements 4.3.6 "The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements" says that those elements can only have phrasing content ("inliny things" like bold or italics or links):

> Content model: Phrasing content.

And https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element says that `button` is phrasing content:

> Categories: Flow content. Phrasing content. [yada]

So you can nest them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not vise vera. Element h2 not allowed as child of element button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).