# Javascript Button onclick change size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aiming to change the background colour onClick. I have done it succesfully however when the colour changes the CSS I have used to style the button no longer applies. How am I able to keep the CSS styling for the button after being clicked

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction(){
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
let colorSindex = -1;
function myyFunction(){
  colorSindex +=1;
  if (colorSindex > colors.length-1) colorSindex = 0;
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]
}
```

```css
.top{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.main{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
    border: black 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
}
button{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
  <ul>Simple</ul>
  <ul>Hex</ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">
   <h1>Background Colour</h1>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you had the content in the button initially wrapped in an `<h1/>` element, but once you updated it with JS you simply replaced the content with the plain text and no wrapping `<h1/>`.  While you *could* update your JS to include the `<h1/>`, the putting a heading element *inside* a button seems dubious to me-- it *may* be allowed, but it seems confusing.  *(**UPDATE**: For what it is worth, it appears [that it is fully valid HTML to have a heading inside a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619072/is-it-semantically-valid-to-put-a-button-inside-a-h2)).*  Instead, I just used the `#btn` `id` on the `<button/>` to apply styles to it using plain CSS that were similar to the `<h1/>` browser default styles; now when the text updates the styling of the button remains intact:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction() {
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length - 1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
let colorSindex = -1;

function myyFunction() {
  colorSindex += 1;
  if (colorSindex > colors.length - 1) colorSindex = 0;
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]
}
```

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  border: black 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Colour Flipper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
    <ul>Simple</ul>
    <ul>Hex</ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">
        Background Colour
    </button>
  </div>
  <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

There are also a number of ways you could do this while retaining the `<h1/>`; one such way would be to simply get the first child of the element you are fetching by `id` by updating the line to `document.getElementById("btn").children[0].innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]`:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction() {
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length - 1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
let colorSindex = -1;

function myyFunction() {
  colorSindex += 1;
  if (colorSindex > colors.length - 1) colorSindex = 0;
  document.getElementById("btn").children[0].innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]
}
```

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  border: black 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Colour Flipper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
    <ul>Simple</ul>
    <ul>Hex</ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">
        <h1>Background Colour</h1>
    </button>
  </div>
  <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This isn't the only way though-- it might be better to give the `<h1/>` it's *own* `id` to use to query it from the DOM.

Comment: Hey Alexander, thanks for your help. Just so I can get my head around it could you please explain how I would update Javascript to include </h1>

Comment: @goosey9 - updated with how to do it w/ JS retaining the `<h1/>`.

Comment: Hey Alexander, if I wanted to make the button the same size for 'backgroun colour' and 'red' for example how would i do that?. I have tried changing the width of the main and also btn but it creates a new box and a smaller one if that makes sense

Comment: You could use the CSS-based approach I showed in the first snippet, and set a fixed button width in the style block targeting the button text.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960500/javascript-button-onclick-change-size#68960567) from @MisterJojo has a working example of that approach.

Answer (score 1):

something like that ?

```js
const
  btn    = document.querySelector('#btn')
, btn_H1 = document.querySelector('#btn h1')
, colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow']
  ;
colors.Index = -1;

btn.onclick = () =>
  {
  colors.Index = ++colors.Index      % colors.length
  let indexNext = (colors.Index + 1) % colors.length

  btn_H1.textContent                  = 'next : ' + colors[ indexNext ]
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[ colors.Index ]
}
```

```css
.top {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-around;
  border          : black 1px solid;
  background      : chartreuse;
  }
.main {
  text-align      : center;
  margin-top      : 15%;
  border          : black 1px solid;
  display         : inline-block;
  position        : relative;
  left            : 40%;
  }
button {
  cursor          : pointer;
  }
button h1 {
  width           : 11em;
  text-align      : center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
  <ul>Simple</ul>
  <ul>Hex</ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn" >
   <h1>Background Colour</h1>
  </button>
</div>
```